# Divs are crashing on different screens

Tags: html, css, resolution

When I coded my website on my 18 inch screen, everything looks perfect! But, once I got over to my Mac (13 inch) everything just went big and the divs were crashing and everything looks extremly zoomed. I know this have something to do with sizing and the position, but I need further help.

One of the CSS it happens to are this code, is something wrong?

```
#client_play {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 125px;
    padding-left: 560px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

Link to page: [like4fame.com/rsps/index.html](http://like4fame.com/rsps/index.html)

Link to my css: http://like4fame.com/rsps/css/css.css

Comment: We can't link between your css and your markup.

Comment: It appears that you've created a design that is hard-coded for a big screen.  The right answer is to create a responsive design that adapts to the screen size.  What specifically do you want help with?  Also, seriously you're making a web page that requires Java?

Comment: yea, i belive its hard-coded for big screen. I need help fixing this. I dont want it to be "hard-coded" for big screen. Yes, its for a game. @jfriend00

Comment: You need to ask a much more specific question because we aren't going to redesign your web site for you.  I'd suggest you start reading about [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) and I've linked one link to get you started, but there are thousands of articles written about it on the web.  That is the general technique you need to follow to allow your site to adapt intelligently to various screen sizes.

Comment: Okei, yes i was kindoff just asking for a little push in the right direction. But is it any ways that it auto zoom after what inch the screen is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point to resolving this issue is to remove the `position: absolute`, `position: relative`, and `position: fixed` styles in your code.

You also want to avoid using `<center>` and go with `text-align: center` or `margin: 0 auto` to center your text or div.

Removing all those styles from your code should help you achieve a better overall website fit for several screen sizes.

I also agree with jfriend00 above about reading about responsive web design.